# c# Detect if a file is able to be deleted

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

i am trying to complete the simple task of detecting if a file is able to be deleted, for example: if a `.dll` is being used by another program you are not able to delete the `.dll` - this is what i want to be able to detect. Well yeah hopefully that makes sense.

So far I've tried the following with no luck:

```
try
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Program Files\MyTestFiles\testing.dll");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to delete file");
}
```

and i've tried:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Program Files\MyTestFiles\testing.dll");
if(File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\MyTestFiles\testing.dll"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Unable to delete file");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully deleted file!");
}
```

Comment: What means with no luck? Doesn´t it work as expected? Do you get an error? Usually `File.Delete` should throw an exception if deletion failed.

Comment: In what way does this not work as expected?  I'd fully expect that first example to either delete the file or fail to do so...

Comment: If such a method existed, there'd be no guarantee that it would still hold when the file is actually to be deleted.  If you don't mind deleting the file yourself, then the best you can do is try.  If it fails, then it is likely that a future attempt will fail and if it succeeds, problem solved.

Comment: In the first example, log the exception that is thrown as well. It may not be failing for the reason you think it is...

Comment: @user1666620 I've tried that, and it says its because the .dll is being used by another program, the thing is i want to be able to detect that -- detect if the .dll is being used by another program so i know whether the file is able to be deleted or not, for example if the .dll is being used by another program and it cannot be deleted i want to be able to output a message letting the user know the file wasn't able to be deleted

Comment: @C0d1ng but aren't you doing that when the delete attempt fails? Just because a program isn't in use at the time of the check doesn't mean it won't be in use at the time of the deletion, and vice versa.

Comment: @C0d1ng: That's *exactly* what your first code sample does.  If this is failing in some way then you have to tell us *how* it's failing.  So far all you've done is described what you want and shown code which does what you want.  So what's the actual question?

Comment: I don't get it. You have perfectly working, correctly written code in your first example. So what is this question asking? How to do it the *wrong* way?

Comment: @CodyGray  the problem is that it doesn't work. No matter what happens Console.WriteLine("Unable to delete file"); is ALWAYS outputted to the console

Comment: Then the file cannot be deleted. Your title is asking the wrong question. It says you want to *detect* if a file can be deleted, but your code already does that. It is detecting that it cannot. If you want to know *why* it cannot be deleted, that's a different question. Probably because it is a DLL that is used by your application. You can't delete something that is in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private bool IsFileLocked()
{
    try
    {
        using (File.Open(@"C:\Program Files\MyTestFiles\testing.dll", FileMode.Open))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // file locked
        return true;
    }
}
```

or for a better solution you can use: [How do I find out which process has a file open?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283)

Comment: This just leads to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Just because a file is unlocked at the present moment, it does not mean it will be unlocked when the request to delete is fired.

Comment: Great answer, works perfectly :)